# Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64 on .net Core

Tags: azure, nuget-package, azure-cognitive-services

I had been using Speaker recognition in c# .net web application via Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition nuget package. For some reasons, i had to integrate Microsoft Speech to text and had to move to .net core. Now when im installing the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64 package on .net core its not updated. Is there any way to make it run on .net core through nuget package and not api calls to the actual service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64 package is targeted using .NetFramework 4.6.1 so it will not work as is even though there is way to add multiple target frameworks for single project as mention below

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

it will not work because `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />` is not compatible with 4.6.1

You could try something like this.

Add another .NetFramework library project to the same solution and reference that project to the main project. so all functionality to actually call speech recognition methods from this nuget package will stay in that class library project ( Need to add code write those helper class )

Project and solution files will look like as follow

** Project file for Class library project based on .NetStandard :**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64" Version="1.0.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Project file for main project based on .netCore project :**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Apart from this you also need to reference class library project in this main .netcore project. right click .netcore project -> Add -> Reference -> select class library project

**Note** : I have tried only till this point and not actually called any speech recognition API. I will try that now